# Zipline installation trouble

Tags: python, installation, jupyter-notebook, zipline, quantopian

After I installed zipline with the anaconda prompt everything was imported and installed correctly. But in the Jupyter notebook, I am getting error like no module called 'matplotlib' or pandas 'DataReader' is not working. When I try to install it in the notebook and restart the kernel, the zipline import is no longer working. How can I solve this? What is wrong with the zipline installation?

Answer (score 1):

zipline has very specific dependencies like pandas 0.18.0 and pandas DataReader 0.8.0. So make sure you have the correct version of those. And by the way, I find the tutorial [here](https://pythonprogramming.net/zipline-local-install-python-programming-for-finance/) very useful.

Hope it could help